# Flatten, append, and relist a list in R

Tags: r, append, flatten

I have two list of lists in R that I'd like join into one list of lists and retain the original structure.  Consider the following as an example:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

a <-  data.frame(c("MA", "V", "UDR"), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
b <-  data.frame(c("MMM", "AAPL"), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
c <-  data.frame(c("MO", "ABT", "XYZ", "Q"), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
d <-  data.frame(c("AA", "NEM", "LUV"), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

lst1 <- list(list(a), list(b))
lst2 <- list(list(c), list(d))
```

I would lie to create a lst3 that appends/joins characters contained in sublist 'a' and 'c', and 'b' and 'd'.

My desired outcome is:

```
lst3 <- list(list(data.frame(c("MA", "V", "UDR", "MO", "ABT", "XYZ", "Q"))), list(data.frame(c("MMM", "AAPL", "AA", "NEM", "LUV"))))
```

I think the code below is close, but I can't quite get it.

```
lst3 <- map(1:2, function(x) {
  append(flatten(lst1[[x]]), flatten(lst2[[x]]))
})
```

Comment: Is there some reason that lst1 and lst2 are not just lists of data frames rather than lists of lists which each hold a single data frame?  Also note that as of R 4.0 stringsAsFactors=FALSE is the default so it need not be specified.

Comment: Yeah, that may be possible.  In my real code, it's just the result of a map function.  So I was trying to replicate as close as I could to the real situation. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `Map` to loop over the corresponding `list` elements, `unlist` and create a nested `data.frame`

```
Map(function(x, y) list(data.frame(col1 = c(unlist(x, 
          use.names = FALSE), unlist(y, use.names = FALSE)))), 
    lst1, lst2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `map2` from `purrr`

```
map2(lst1, lst2, ~unname(c(unlist(.x), unlist(.y))))
# [[1]]
# [1] "MA"  "V"   "UDR" "MO"  "ABT" "XYZ" "Q"  
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "MMM"  "AAPL" "AA"   "NEM"  "LUV"
```